# How do you generalise that the probability of "head" occurring on a coin is 0.5?

Tags: probability

Supposedly I toss a coin 1000 times a day for a period of 10 days. Each day the probability of head occurring on the coin changes. For instance - 670 times getting a head on day 1, 567 times getting a head on day 2 and so on. So each time, the probability of a head occuring isn't 0.5, so can someone please explain why we generalise that the probability of a head occuring on tossing of a coin is 0.5??

Comment: Are you asking why if the probability is 0.5 you don't see exactly of the samples to be heads?

Comment: You appear to conflate *frequency* (a random value) with *probability* (a fixed value used in a model of the coin).  You also seem to posit a situation in which "we" assume something obviously contrary to fact: namely, that a coin showing heads 670 times out of 1000 is fair: obviously not.

Comment: How do you get 1, 567 heads out of  1000 tosses on day two?

Comment: @Bruce The comma separates the preceding clause from a new clause.  It is not part of a number.

Comment: @whuber so the coin is biased, is what you mean, right?

Comment: What would you conclude after seeing such a high proportion of heads?

Comment: Just for Days 1 & 2 with counts 576 & 567, the test for fair coins both days uses `prop.test(c(576,567),c(1000,1000), p=c(.5,.5))$p.val`, which returns $1.613274e-09$ very near $0,$ so coins not fair.

Comment: Results in my answer are from my fictitious data, not from data (misread) in question.

Comment: @whuber but 670 times was just for day 1, but when you average them all out, would it result to 50% probability that heads will show up? Consider that I've done this set of trials for 10 consecutive days but I chose to select 5 days randomly and took in their results. So now, would it still remain 50% probability?

Comment: @tim yes, but I just don't consider a particular day during the test. Any chances that their average (of the days I chose) would result in 0.5??

Comment: Just think about day 1.  That is *overwhelming* evidence the coin was not fair during all of day 1.  It is difficult to determine what you're really trying to ask, because you obviously aren't asking about flipping coins and the meaning you impute to "probability" looks slippery.

Comment: @whuber my question was if you generalise the 0.5 based on the possible outcomes or if you base them on the number of times you repeat the experiment?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "generalise" nor "possible outcomes."  This is because your meaning of "probability" is unclear and what you consider to be an experiment is also not evident.

Comment: @whuber Let me explain myself. So when you toss a coin, you either get heads or tails. So these are the two possible outcomes I meant. So the probability of getting a head on tossing of a coin is 1/2. Now, supposedly ( just an assumption) if I toss a coin 1000 times and get heads 544 times, so for that particular trial, the probability would be 0.54 which is not equal to 0.5. So are we approximating the results we get?

Comment: Let me return to my first comment: you confuse *frequency* with *probability.* In your experiment, the coin turned up heads 0.544 of the time.  Period.  That is not the same as--and almost certainly differs a little from--any probability the coin might actually have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134489/discussion-between-rhithik-and-whuber).

Comment: Perhaps this will just be more confusing, but to my knowledge, the probability that a given run will have exactly 50% heads actually goes to 0 as the run’s length goes to infinity.

Comment: (The probability of heads on any flip is still 0.5, of course; my point is just that this doesn’t always mean what our intuitions would suggest.)

Comment: IIRC the stats prof followed this observation with “this is an argument against frequentism,” although I might be misremembering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a straightforward 10 day experiment with 1000 tosses each day
with a fair coin you might see the following numbers of Heads on the 10 days. [Sampling in R.]

```
set.seed(2022)
x = rbinom(10, 1000, .5)
x
[1] 488 488 502 493 495 490 524 487 500 506
```

If someone doesn't know you used a fair coin, then they might use the procedure `prop.test` to see whether the Heads probability each
day might be $0.5.$

```
prop.test(x, rep(1000,10), p=rep(.5,10))

        10-sample test for given proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  x out of rep(1000, 10), null probabilities rep(0.5, 10)
X-squared = 4.988, df = 10, p-value = 0.892
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
null values:
 prop 1  prop 2  prop 3  prop 4  prop 5  prop 6  prop 7  prop 8  prop 9 prop 10 
    0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5 
sample estimates:
 prop 1  prop 2  prop 3  prop 4  prop 5  prop 6  prop 7  prop 8  prop 9 prop 10 
  0.488   0.488   0.502   0.493   0.495   0.490   0.524   0.487   0.500   0.506
```

The null hypothesis is that $p=P(\mathrm{Heads}) = 0.5$ each day, against
the alternative hypothesis that $p \ne 0.5$ on one or more of the days.
$H_0$ cannot be rejected because the P-value $0.892 > 0.05 = 5\%.$

Clearly, not all daily proportions of Heads are exactly $0.5,$ but
the random variation (among observed proportions, $0.487$ to $0.524)$ is not more than
would be expected by chance.

By contrast, if you got results as in the vector `y` below, then someone might
wonder whether you used a fair coin each day.

```
set.seed(228)
y = rbinom(10, 1000, seq(.2, .8, len=10))
y
[1] 182 250 332 408 456 508 611 668 772 809
```

Then `prop.test` can be used to see if Heads probabilities
are all the same (the default null hypothesis, in case nothing
else is specified in the input).s
prop.test(y, rep(1000,10))

```
    10-sample test for equality of proportions 
    without continuity correction

data:  y out of rep(1000, 10)
X-squared = 1649.3, df = 9, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
 prop 1  prop 2  prop 3  prop 4  prop 5  prop 6  prop 7  prop 8  prop 9 prop 10 
  0.182   0.250   0.332   0.408   0.456   0.508   0.611   0.668   0.772   0.809
```

For this test, the P-value is very near $0$ so $H_0$ is rejected.

*Notes:* (1) Both versions of `prop.test` are roughly equivalent to chi-squared
tests. You could use chi-squared tests if you like, but I find
the output from `prop.test` to be more informative for current
purposes.

(2) This Answer is based on one possible interpretation of your Question, which I found to be somewhat vague.
If you have something else in mind, please *edit your question*
to be more specific.

Comment: No, you've pretty much interpreted my question in the right way. The coin being biased is what we conclude after the hypothesis test. Thank you for explaining!

Comment: It might be useful to explain why the null and alternative hypotheses are what they are and not the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to CV, Rhithik.

I think there is a foundational concept that you may need to understand a little better: when we say "something is **random** (like the value of a single coin flip, or of 1,000 coin flips)" in the statistical sense, what we mean is that **the values of specific "realizations" (or "observations", etc.) cannot be known in advance—we can only speak of such events (single flips, or 1,000 flips) in terms of probabilities and probability distributions**.

If we were to say "exactly 0.5, or 500 of these 1,000 flips **will** come up heads" we are no longer speaking of probabilities or probability distributions—precise articulations in the language of uncertainty—but of dead certainties.

So what does this precise value of **0.5** mean? In a probabilistic sense, it means we believe that a single coin flip has exactly as much chance of coming up heads, as it does of coming up tails. When we extend that belief about the behavior of a single coin flip to 1,000 coin flips, we use the binomial distribution to describe the probability of realizing 498 heads, or 499 heads, or 500, heads, etc. And if you play with the binomial distribution, you will find that while exactly 500 heads is the "most likely" realization for 1,000 flips, it is by no means the *only* possible realization (indeed, 498, 499, 501, 502 all have probabilities *almost* as high as 500). Still, that binomial distribution, parameterized by $p=0.5$ is **our *probabilistic* description of $\boldsymbol{n}$ coin flips with probability of heads of $\boldsymbol{p=0.5}$ for an individual flip.**

To sum up the "0.5" of the fair coin does not describe realized **sample statistics** (i.e. the actually realized number of 1,000 flips coming up heads on a given day), but rather describes a part of our conceptual model, part of the **probability distribution** of observing all possible values.

Answer (score 1):

> why we generalise that the probability of a head occuring on tossing of a coin is 0.5??

I don't think you can make that generalization unless you further assume that the probability of head on each day is itself a random variable with expectation 0.5 (e.g. one day is 0.6, another day is 0.4, etc. on average it is 0.5).